# Cannot access "Visual Line" in Vim in PuTTY

Tags: vim, centos, putty

I am SSH'ing to a server (running `CentOS release 5.4 (Final)`).  I opened `vim`, and when I hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to try to get into "Visual Line" mode, all I get is a beep noise.

Why?  Why can't I access visual mode in Vim?  `echo $TERM` says `xterm`.

I SSH'd into another computer (running Debian), and pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> worked exactly as I'd expect (this machine also has `echo $TERM` equal to `xterm`).

What setting do I need to check to make Vim act the way I want?  Or how can I get into visual mode without being beeped at?

Comment: Are you sure that vim is actually installed and not nvi or something else with a symlink?

Comment: @Zoredache: When I open `vim`, it says: `VIM - Vi IMproved version 7.0.237`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does "`vim --version`" show "Tiny Version" immediately before the feature list? If so, that particular Vim binary probably does not have support for visual mode.  Check the actual feature list for `+visual`/`-visual`.  If it is a minus, that confirms that the support is not there.

As this is CentOS 5, I would recommend trying this to get a fully enabled Vim (as root):

```
yum install vim-enhanced
```

Comment: `Tiny version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-): -visual`.  I didn't know there was `vim-minimal` vs `vim-enhanced`.  On most other linux distros, it's just `vim`.

Comment: Yep.  That is exactly why it wasn't working!  Thanks so much :-D

Comment: @RocketHazmat, no. On most other distros, the default Vim is vim-minimal or vim-tiny and you must manually install a proper vim.

Comment: @romainl: I use Arch Linux and Gentoo :-)